# Remove "restart" option from menu

Tags: unity, 14.04, shutdown, menu

When I click the gear icon to open the system menu on my PC, these options are presented:

- Suspend
- **Restart...**
- Shutdown...

The restart options seems redundant, because it literally does the same thing as the shutdown one - brings up the overlay menu that is focused on the shutdown shortcut.

I thought this option was supposed to be already removed. In fact, it doesn't exist on my laptop.

**How can I bring the system menu back it its normal/original state?**

Both computers running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Very strange. Do you have any programs that might have caused this?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the linked one ***at all***. Mitch it's quite obvious from the title that my question refers to *removing* the option, and the one you linked to has "How do I **get** restart..." in its title.

Comment: @Tim I have Unity Tweak Tool installed, but I still don't know if that's what caused it.

Comment: @Mitch not a duplicate - opposite questions!

Comment: However, the answer may help - try ticking it if it's unticked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15274/discussion-between-tim-and-jcz).

Comment: That's strange, I don't have the option to restart..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing a fresh install, the Restart option is not there by default.

You can use Dconf Editor to remove it.  To install dconf editor, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Once installed, type dconf in Dash, and then click on dconf Editor.  Once open navigate to apps --> indicator-session --> and tick that option.  See image below.

[image]

[image]

Restart so changes can take effect.

Comment: The bug on this was never completely fixed so by default restart does show for a couple of sec's right after log in. (then usually disappears.) Disabling in dconf will make it never show so not a bad solution for those where it doesn't go away. Whether that affects other times when a restart notify should show up ,no clue.  However your picture is highlighting the wrong option to remove the restart option only.